# copy files to device with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have this task which copies a video file to emulator

```
task copyFiles(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'adb', 'push', './src/androidTest/raw/testVideo.mp4', '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/'
}
```

and

```
build.finalizedBy(copyFiles)
```

but it is not working. what I want is that the video should be copied to device, but I think that at this point (build) there is no adb available. how can I do this?

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? What are your specific symptoms?

Comment: the video isn't being copied, just that

Comment: FWIW, [this Gradle plugin](https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-command-plugin) claims to support push and pull operations. You might try it instead of using an `Exec` task. Also, for your task to work, `adb` would have to be in your `PATH`. You might also try using a fully-qualified path to the source video, instead of your relative one, to see if that changes anything.

Comment: I tested this functions using `gradle copyFiles` after the emulator was up and running and it works...but do not work during the build. I'll take a look at that pulgin